# Where does puppet pull the hostname info to name the certs in the ssl directory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, puppet, hostname, amazon-ami

When I spin up my AWS machine, the first thing I do is run `hostnamectl set-hostname myhost.test.com` but then when I install and run puppet, it is pulling `standard-1-ami.test.com` as the cert name. `standard-1-ami` is the name of my AMI.

Where is it getting this name from on the OS?

Comment: This instance hostname setting is happening how; a `user_data` argument in Terraform? A Puppet provisioner in Packer? Hostname setting on AWS can be finicky, and Puppet relies on the FQDN by default, but you can also configure it via the Puppet conf: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/config_file_main.html#config-sections

Comment: I say in the original post how I am setting the host name. I am not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: My first guess would be that Puppet is using the `hostname` command to determine the hostname.  Which result does that give?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well. Every time I make a new machine, without setting the hostname in a userdata script, I have this issue. I have noticed that the initial hostname is cached somewhere in memory.

Here's how I fix it:
Hostname: new_host ; IP: 192.168.10.50 ; DomainName: inside.myhouse.com

`hostnamectl set-hostname new_host`
`echo "192.168.10.50  new_host.inside.myhouse.com new_host" >> /etc/hosts`
`echo "new_host" > /etc/hostname`
`service network restart`
These 3 places are where the hostname "lives" or "can be retrieved.
To validate my configs, I run these 3 commands:
`$ hostname`
`new_host`
`$ hostname -f`
`new_host.inside.myhouse.com`
`hostname -i`
`192.168.10.50`

Note that, if your prompt is set to have your hostname displayed, your prompt may not change until you log back in. If the hostname & hostname -f commands work, you can run puppet and it should use the correct hostname.

BTW: I use Red Hat. YMMV.